# How do you print an array if it has more than 2 index?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Here is my code when i printed it, the print would not show the expected result and I tried making the array into string but the result lead to printing a boxes.

```
c=0;
array1=[];
for r=1:1
    while c<=5
     value = "Enter value for index " + c + ":";
     array1(r,c+1)=input(value);
     c=c+1;
    end  
end


[maxval]= max(array1);
[index1] = find(ismember(array1, max(array1(:))));
[minval]= min(array1);
[index2] = find(ismember(array1, min(array1(:))));

fprintf("The highest value is %d located in index %d.\n", maxval,index1)
fprintf("The lowest value is %d located in index %d.", minval,index2)
```

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB follows a base-1 indexing scheme, but if you insist on using a base-0 indexing approach you can offset the values retrieved by the `ismember()` function by subtracting `1`. Below I added some pre-allocation to the array size and reduced the script to include only the while-loop.

```
clc;
c = 1;
Array_Size = 6;
array1 = zeros(1,Array_Size);

while c <= Array_Size
 value = "Enter value for index " + num2str(c-1) + ": ";
 array1(c)=input(value);
 c=c+1;
end  

[maxval] = max(array1);
[index1] = find(ismember(array1, max(array1)));
[minval] = min(array1);
[index2] = find(ismember(array1, min(array1)));

index1 = index1 - 1;
index2 = index2 - 1;

fprintf("The highest value is %d located in index %d.\n", maxval,index1);
fprintf("The lowest value is %d located in index %d.\n", minval,index2);
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment, but how do you print if there are multiple indices to print like the value of index1 has 1 and 5. 

Here is the sample result that I would like to reach
Enter value for index 0: 24
Enter value for index 1: 64
Enter value for index 2: 12
Enter value for index 3: 12
Enter value for index 4: 8
 
The highest value is 64 located in index 1.
The lowest value is 12 located in index 2, 3.

also, I'm sorry if I posted this late.